# Wallaby js in Visual Studio : tests in different folder

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, jasmine, wallaby.js

I am using a wallaby.js with jasmine for FE unit tests.
I would like to separate the Tests from Productive Code in such a way,
that i create two projects - A and A_Test. All productive code is in A and all test code is in A_Test.

The problem with wallaby is, that i can not make it work for such a configuration since it seems to not support the relative '../../' notation.

My example json configuration:

```
    {
  "files": [
    "../../A/src/*.js"  <--- This part doesn't work
  ],

  "tests": [
    "test/*Spec.js"
  ],
  "testFramework": "jasmine@2.2.1"
}
```

(It seems to be wallabys fault since my test in jasmine works fine with ../ paths, also a full path doesn't work)

Do you know if it is possible to support such a structure?

Thanks!

Comment: Since 1.0.7 it is possible to have wallaby.js config as a solution item - github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues/153#issuecomment-111824785

Comment: Hello!,Thanks for the quick fix. For some time it should do the trick. Is there a way however, to support also a relative paths within a project's own wallaby-jasmine.json? Or are you planning to support it? Ans one more question if i may ask:  Regarding WallabyTrial example : In Visual Studio Proffessional 2013 I can not start wallaby on a wallaby-jasmine.json in seperate solution. Do I have to download also a new extension to VS to make it work?

Comment: We are planning to support it - feel free to vote and follow the feature request - https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues/68. Regarding wallaby update - it updates automatically when it starts. So you need to start it, for example by using your previous json file in the project, after it starts it will update itself, prompt to restart VS and after the restart you'll be able to have wallaby config as one of your Solution Items.

Answer (score 0):

I added a wallaby.json file to the visual studio solution items. 
This was physically placed just outside the folders of 2 projects. One called Ckm and the other called CkmClientUnitTest.

The following wallby.json resulted in running the javascript test from a separate project, but including the sut javascript's from the main project.  jquery is included in the tests from the main project.

```
{
  "files": [
    "style/calculator.css",
    {
      "pattern": "Ckm/wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "instrument": false
    },
    {
      "pattern": "Ckm/wwwroot/Mashup/lib/*.js"
    }
  ],
  "tests": [
    "Ckm.ClientUnitTest/wwwroot/Mashup/lib/*TestJasmine.js"
  ],
  "testFramework": "jasmine@2.1.3"
}
```